# System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel AutoSize

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Thanks for giving this a once-over.

**The setup:**

1. I have a TableLayoutPanel on a Form with AutoSize=true and AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink.
2. The TableLayoutPanel also is AutoSize=true and AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink.
3. Finally, in the TableLayoutPanel, I've got a Label with AutoSize=true.

**The reality:**

When I put a larger amount of text into the Label, I expect it's going to autosize to get large.  If the form goes over 650 pixels in height, I want to bump the font size down on the Label until the form size goes back down to under 650 pixels tall.  Unfortunately, this doesn't occur.  Instead, the form remains tall (800+ pixels) and it loops below until the font size is at the minimum (6) without visibly resizing the form, table, or label.

Here is the code I'm using.  Be gentle :)

```
  While Me.Height > 650 And (FontSize = -1 Or FontSize > 5)

        If FontSize < 3 Then 'hack
            FontSize = 12
        Else
            FontSize -= 1
        End If

        'I hoped this would just resize everything (label, TableLayoutPanel, Form)
        lblText.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", FontSize)

        'Then tried to force it to resize
        TableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout()

        Me.Refresh()   'Maybe unnecessary
        Me.PerformAutoScale()   'Necessary?
        Me.Size = New Size(558, 200)  'Feeble attempt to force a resize

    End While
```